# Use cheap graphic tablet as a trackpad

Tags: input-device, touchpad, graphics-tablet

since I have zero experience with tablets, I have a question to ask about this.

Is it possible to use (cheap) graphic tablet as a trackpad device, with your finger, and how (if possible at all)?

I have a special application for trackpad (x/y controller), and since external (usb) trackpads are *very* hard to find where I live (but cheap tablets are available everywhere). Most of search results on G are about using trackpad as a cheap tablet device, but I need it the other way around.

Any thoughts?

Underlying OS is (or, will be) Win/Mac.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I doubt it, as they are completely different.  While touchpads use [capacitive sensing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitive_sensing), graphics tablets use something else entirely ([electromagnetic induction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_tablet) apparently).

My Wacom Intuos works without the pen having to touch the tablet, as that is how you move the mouse pointer around the screen.  You only press down on the tablet when you are dragging, drawing, painting, etc, and it can sense how hard you are pressing down on it.

[According to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_tablet#Operation), there are capacitive tablets available, so you would have to find one of those before even starting to think about the possibility of using it as a touchpad.